# Solid heading for onecolumn and twocolumn document

Tags: spacing, width

I need advice on creating a consistent solid heading style for a document that has both one column and two column pages. In one column mode, the heading should fill the entire page, but in two column mode, the heading should only fill the width of the column.

Something like this almost works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\solidheading}[2][blue]{
  \sffamily\colorbox{#1}{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{#2}\hspace{0.6\linewidth}}
}

\begin{document}

\onecolumn

\solidheading{Page wide heading}

\lipsum

\twocolumn

\solidheading{Column wide heading}

\lipsum

\solidheading{Another column wide heading}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

But the heading width is a little too wide in the `\twocolumn` environment and a little too narrow in a `\onecolumn` environment.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

After a bit of struggling, I realised that I was being silly and added the line width to the text.

So changing this line:

```
\sffamily\colorbox{#1}{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{#2}\hspace{0.6\linewidth}}
```

To this:

```
\noindent\sffamily\colorbox{#1}{\makebox[1.0\linewidth][l]{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{#2}}}
```

Helps a lot, but then the following lines in two column mode are thrown out a little. So it's not correct yet.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for the friendly reminder Christian. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `\parbox` with a width of

```
\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep\relax
```

in

```
\newcommand{\solidheading}[2][blue]{%
  \noindent\sffamily\colorbox{#1}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}%
     {\bfseries\textcolor{white}{#2}%
       }}%
       \vskip1ex %% adjust this as suitable
}
```

May be you should put `\sffamily` inside the `\parbox`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcommand{\solidheading}[2][blue]{%
  \noindent\sffamily\colorbox{#1}{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\columnwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}%
     {\bfseries\textcolor{white}{#2}%
       }}%
       \vskip1ex %% adjust this as suitable
}

\begin{document}

\onecolumn

\solidheading{Page wide heading}

\kant

\twocolumn

\solidheading{Column wide heading}

\kant

\solidheading{Another column wide heading}

\kant


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Harish! It works like a charm!!! +1 for kantlipsum ;-)

Comment: @JacobusR You are welcome :-)